# Multiple Random Advert Divs on Same Page PHP/JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Ive exhausted my amateur scripting skills and seeking help.

Here is my sites main index and the current working script with one set of adds randomly displaying on my home page.

**http://blessone.netau.net/**

Ive managed after alot of tries with different codes ive come across to come up with this.

```
divs = ['d1','d2','d3','d4'];

function hideDivs() {
for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++)
document.getElementsByClassName('adbox');

}

function showDiv() {
hideDivs(); //hide them all before we show the next one.
var randomDiv = divs[Math.floor(Math.random()*divs.length)];
var div = document.getElementsByClassName(randomDiv).style.display =
'block';

setTimeout(showDiv,500); //set a delay before showing the next div

}`
```

Im trying to display a div randomly on my home page from a set of divs in "adverts/pop_left_ad.php"` Popular Products.

Works great!

But one problem. When i try to use.....

```
<?php include("adverts/pop_left_ad.php"); ?>
```

...twice on one page it doesn't give me two different random divs on my page, no matter where i place them. I am using different files for each set of divs that are than called upon randomly by their calling div.

I should point out im NOT sure how to edit the JS for my second inclusion. Do i only add a series of div ID's in there??? What elements do i change in the JS?

I have now learnt that the issue is my id setup and have changed that to a class setup.
So i need help making the additional changed to my JS to incorporate the Classes and so on.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: So, "adverts/pop_left_ad.php" just contains the Javascript you posted? Have you tried viewing the generated source of the page?  I'm betting it'll be rather revealing...

Comment: no it only contains the divs. I have the Javascript in the header of my home page where in the body im calling on the "adverts/pop_left_ad.php"!

Comment: "adverts/pop_left_ad.php" only contains divs and a link to my css file

Comment: Do a view source, please.  Something is in there twice that shouldn't be.  You can't duplicate IDs, for example.  Having two divs that are id=d1 is going to produce hilariously incorrect results.

Comment: by the way hi Charles.  Also i didnt quite understand the generated source of the page tip...

Comment: Hi Charles. Im still battling with this JS. Any chance you can guide me on what im suppose to change on my JS above to accomodate my changes of containers from Divs to Class's? Really Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue appears to be that you are using id attributes for your divs.  This is fine where there is only one copy of d1, d2, d3, d4 in the code, but if it's included multiple times, getElementById will have trouble differentiating between the different divs with the same id.

what I would do change the id attirbutes for each of d1 through d4 to class attributes (and do the same for the contents of each of d1-d4, e.g. make id="adTitle" into class="adTitle"), then wrap the set of ads in a div with a class attribute named something like "adbox"

from there, you modify your code to get all divs that have the adbox class, then loop through the interior divs with classname d1-d4 like you do currently. with jQuery you can do something like `$('.adbox').each()` which makes the looping dead simple, but you can also use `document.getElementsByClassName('adbox')` if you want to stick with pure JS

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the reply. I changed the id's to classes and in my JS changed *******document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display = 'none';******
 to *********document.getElementsByClassName('adbox')******* .....However its now not returning anything now, Anything else i should be fiddling with in the JS?

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements that have that class.  you'll have to add code to loop through that array.  plus code to get the elements with the class names d1-d4 within that div (something like `div.getElementsByClassName('d1')`, etc)

Comment: /noob /clueless...Tried to have a go but not getting it. Ive only got my head around html, css and some php and im completely lost with JS atm. Kind of just using a cut and paste script that i cant understand. Cant get my head around it. Any chance of a bit more guidance.

Comment: Assuming that `divs = ['d1','d2','d3','d4'];` gets replaces by `class= ['d1','d2','d3','d4'];` is as far as ive got:)

Comment: take a look at the jQuery docs and the [Mozilla Developers Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).  That should give you guidance with code samples on how to do a lot of basic javascript related stuff

Comment: Hi Pete. I had a look at the Moz Dev Link and im still clueless. Tried to find other alternative codes that might work with no luck. Any guidance of how my Jscript should look with the class setup.